# Derivation of Lagrangian in generalized coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor

I am reading Mark Tuckerman's *Statistical Mechanics* and I am going through his derivation of the Lagrangian in generalized coordinates, using the mass metric tensor $G$.
He defines kinetic energy as
\begin{align}
K(q,\dot{q}) &= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{\alpha=1}^{3N}\sum_{\beta =1}^{3N}\left[\sum_{i=1}^N m_i \frac{\partial r_i}{\partial q_{\alpha}} \frac{\partial r_i}{\partial q_{\alpha}} \right]\dot{q_{\alpha}}\dot{q_{\beta}} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{\alpha=1}^{3N}\sum_{\beta =1}^{3N} G_{\alpha \beta}(q_1,q_2,...)\dot{q_{\alpha}}\dot{q_{\beta}}
\end{align}
And potential energy is simply
$$U\equiv U(q_1, q_2, ...)$$

So the Lagrangian is
\begin{align}
L = K-U
\end{align}
Now plugging in the above definitions into the Euler-Lagrange equation gives:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q_{\gamma}}} \right) - \frac{\partial L}{\partial q_{\gamma}} = 0
\end{align}
The potential energy part is trivial, $\frac{\partial U}{\partial q_{\gamma}}$.
Unpacking, the KE part of the above equation, I get,
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial K}{\partial \dot{q_{\gamma}}}\right)&= \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial \dot{q_{\gamma}}} \frac{1}{2} G_{\alpha \beta}(q_1,q_2,...)\dot{q_{\alpha}}\dot{q_{\beta}}\right)\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{1}{2}(G_{\alpha \beta} \delta_{\alpha \gamma}\dot{q}_{\beta} + G_{\alpha \beta} \dot{q}_{\alpha}\delta_{\gamma \beta}) \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\left( G_{\gamma \beta} \dot{q}_{\beta} + G_{\alpha \gamma} \dot{q}_{\alpha}\right)
\end{align}
This is where I actually don't know how to simplify further to get,

\begin{align}
\sum _{\beta=1}^{3N}G_{\gamma \beta}\ddot{q}_{\beta}+\sum_{\alpha=1}^{3N}\sum_{\beta=1}^{3N} \left[ \frac{\partial G_{\gamma \beta}}{\partial q_{\alpha}} - \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial G_{\alpha \beta}}{\partial q_{\gamma} } \right]\dot{q}_{\alpha} \dot{q}_{\beta}
\end{align}
which is what Tuckermann has in his book. How do I get to this result?

Comment: Note that the kinetic energy seems to depend on the $q$'s through the mass metric tensor. EDIT: Therefore, you have to take into account also the kinetic part in order to compute $\partial_{q_{\gamma}} L$

Comment: Thanks @Javi for the reply. Could you possibly expand on that?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the mass metric tensor $G_{\alpha\beta}$ is symmetric, that is $G_{\alpha\beta}=G_{\beta\alpha}.$ So your kinetic part
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}(G_{\gamma\beta}\dot{q}_{\beta}+G_{\alpha\gamma}\dot{q}_{\alpha})=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}(G_{\gamma\beta}\dot{q}_{\beta}+G_{\gamma\alpha}\dot{q}_{\alpha}).$$
Since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are dummy indices, they can be summed up to give
$\frac{dG_{\gamma\beta}\dot{q}_{\beta}}{dt}.$ Then the second term in Eq.(1.4.19) is simply the partial derivative of $G_{\alpha\beta}$ with respect to $q_{\gamma}$.